# AJAX How To Access Map List JSON using Spring on JSP

Tags: ajax, json, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to populate comboboxes with `list` and `list2` data using the follow code:

```
$("#collectionPeriod").change(
    function(){
        alert('collectionPeriodIndex === ' + $(this).find('option:selected').index());
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/collectionMonitorCampus.htm",
            data: {collectionPeriodIndex: $(this).find('option:selected').index(), sYearIndexNext: $('#sYear').find('option:selected').index(), sYearVal: $('#sYear').find('option:selected').val()},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#submission").prop("disabled", false);
                $("#submission").empty();
                $("#category").empty();

                $.each($.map(data.list, function(val) {
                     $('#category').append(new Option(val,val));
                     console.log("val1 " + val);
                }));

                $.each($.map(data.list2, function(val) {
                     $('#submission').append(new Option(val,val));
                     console.log("val2 " + val);
                }));
            }
        });

    });
```

The problem I have is that the console only prints `val2`values and `val`is completely ignored. Is there an error on how I'm accessing this data?

My controller `list` and `list2` is defined as `List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>();`

The model that I'm putting `list` and `list1 in is`Map model = new HashMap();`

and I'm returning the ModelAndView as:

`return new ModelAndView("jsonView", model);`

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both `.each()` and `.map()` are functions that are able to access the elements in your `data.list`.
Read more about **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** and **[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)**

You can use one or the other, you don't need both:

```
$.map(data.list, function(val, i) {
    $('#category').append(new Option(val,val));
    console.log("val1 " + val);
});
```

Or

```
$(data.list).each(function(i, val) {
    $('#category').append(new Option(val,val));
    console.log("val1 " + val);
});
```

Pay attention to the arguments order, `.each()` is in different order from `.map()`.